# How can I set the arrow i want on the far right of the button instead of right next to the text?

Tags: html, css

So I am working with html and css, I got this button with some text in it, and then an arrow in a span right next to it, but I want the arrow to be on the far right of the button and not right next to the text/placholder

Here is my code:

```css
.buttonTest {
  text-indent: 20px;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-padding-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  height: 9rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonTest">
  <span style="font-family:CompactDisplayLight; font-size: 20px; color:pink">Button Push<span> ^ </span></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your HTML structure slightly you can use a combination of `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` on the button element:

```css
.buttonTest {
  text-indent: 20px;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-padding-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  height: 9rem;
  font-family: CompactDisplayLight;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: pink;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonTest">
  <span>Button Push</span>
  <span> ^ </span>
</button>
```

You could use the same technique with your current HTML structure, but you would target the first `span` using the child combinator (`>`):

```css
.buttonTest {
  text-indent: 20px;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-padding-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  height: 9rem;
  font-family: CompactDisplayLight;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: pink;
}

.buttonTest > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonTest">
  <span>Button Push <span> ^ </span></span>    
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttonTest {
  text-indent: 20px;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-padding-start: 3rem;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
  height: 9rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonTest">
  <span style="font-family:CompactDisplayLight; font-size: 20px; color:pink">Button Push</span> 
  <span>^</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .buttonTest {
            text-indent: 20px;
            width: 97%;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            -webkit-padding-start: 3rem;
            padding-inline-start: 3rem;
            font-size: 3.5rem;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
            box-shadow: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
            height: 9rem;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="buttonTest">
        <span style="font-family:CompactDisplayLight; font-size: 20px; color:pink;position:absolute;right:10px">Button Push<span> ^ </span></span>
    </button>
</body>
```

If I understand right, That should works.